# What jobs are in the Mime (reskinned Criminal) career track in the mainland China release?

Tags: the-sims, the-sims-series

In original American version of the Sims 1, your characters could choose a criminal career path, and could be promoted through ten jobs from pickpocket to criminal mastermind. According to a [list of fun facts made by EA](https://www.ea.com/en-gb/news/celebrate-the-sims-sweet-sixteen-now-and-then), this was changed in the localization for mainland China.

> In order to ship The Sims in China, the Life of Crime career track was renamed to Life of Mime, and all the content changed to make it mime-themed.

I think that's a great choice once I realized that criminals and mimes both wear striped shirts. But I think that it would be hard to come up with ten distinct mime jobs, especially if they're trying to match the stats of the original criminal jobs. Do any of you know how they named the ten mime jobs?

I don't know Chinese, so it's tough for me to search for the right terms and comb through hits. The query I've tried is "模拟人生 默劇"

I also found [this website](https://www.3dmgame.com/gl/3371118_13.html) that lists criminal jobs in The Sims 4. I'm not sure if Sims 4 got rid of the mime career track, or if that is not the mainland China version.

Notes:

- I see in the wiki that the Taiwan release doesn't have that change, so I'm not asking about that.
- I'd accept an answer for any game in The Sims series if it's hard to get an answer for The Sims 1.
- I'd accept one vaguely remembered job title if it's hard to get a complete answer.
- A stunningly perfect answer would also include full job descriptions pictures of work uniforms, commuting car, chance cards, and any changes to work hours/wages/skills/career track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though this change was only made to the Simplified Chinese version; the Traditional Chinese version has the usual Life of Crime career track, with all the normal jobs. Rather than being mime specific, it was actually changed to the comedy path. [From what I can find](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/c3511c3f02768e9951e738ad.html), the jobs in that track were:

> 喜剧新手街头喜剧演员知名喜剧演员喜剧高手戏剧协会发起人戏剧协会助理喜剧评论员喜剧演员老板喜剧大师

Which Google Translate assures me translates to something like:

> Novice Comedian, Street Comedian, Well Known Comedian, Comedy Master, Drama Association Initiate, Assistant to Drama Association, Comedy Commentator, Comedian Boss, Comedy Master.

Interestingly, I found [a forum post](https://game.ali213.net/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=1265446&pid=11512687) of people who missed the crime path and wanted to change the comedy path back to the crime one, along with the icons and descriptions to restore that path! This is for The Sims 2, I believe.

Comment: Wow, great! I see some of the career paths listed on that page but I can't see the comedian one without logging in. Would you mind pasting it in with bullet points, blank lines, or commas to separate the job titles?

Comment: This answer is all about Sims 2. I'll wait to see if we can get a Sims 1 answer before accepting. Even if there is a Sims 1 answer, this answer really enriches the question, and I'm so thankful.